# how to reduce the default space between two textviews in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:textSize="@dimen/logo_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
    android:text="@string/a" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:layout_below="@id/a"
    android:textSize="@dimen/logo_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
    android:text="@string/b" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

will result in two lines of text with a certain space between them. I want to get rid of this space and have the two lines string being closer to each other. Is that possible?

Comment: can you put all the layout file please?

Comment: There is no default space between two elements-  its literally 0 pixels.  If you're seeing some, its built into the font you're using.

Comment: I edited that with the actual code I use. Maybe that's build in my theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to get rid of this space and have the two lines string being
>   closer to each other

Try this add `android:includeFontPadding="false"` to the `textview` to reduce the space between the texts

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="HELLO" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/a"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="GOOD JOB Buddy" />
```

**Edit**

also add  `android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"` for the top textview `@+id/a`...

it will force to reduce the gap between the two textviews.

Comment: doesn't make any difference - I updated my edit with the actual code I use (just it case the omitted parts make any differences)